# MacOS client has completely different file permissions from Ubuntu Server

Tags: networking, server, permissions, ssh, samba

So we have a problem at our company...
We got a new server and we are using Ubuntu Server 17.10.
The Samba Version we have installed is 4.6.7-Ubuntu.

The problem is that we have these permissions on the server:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 corpuser corpuser 4096 Mar 9 2017 virtuell1/
drwxr-xr-x 4 corpuser corpuser 4096 Oct 12 2011 virtuell10/
drwxr-xr-x 3 corpuser corpuser 4096 Jun 16 2014 virtuell2/
drwxr-xr-x 3 corpuser corpuser 4096 Feb 24 2014 virtuell3/
drwxr-xr-x 3 corpuser corpuser 4096 Jun 24 2016 virtuell4/
drwxr-xr-x 3 corpuser corpuser 4096 Jul 22 2016 virtuell5/
drwxr-xr-x 4 corpuser corpuser 4096 Jan 22 10:25 virtuell6/
drwxr-xr-x 3 corpuser corpuser 4096 May 11 2017 virtuell7/
drwxr-xr-x 5 corpuser corpuser 4096 Jan 16 12:24 virtuell8/
drwxr-xr-x 3 corpuser corpuser 4096 Mar 28 2014 virtuell9/
```

and when we access the server as a client in MacOS (Version: 10.12.6) we get to see these permissions:

```
drwx------  1 mr.robot  staff      16384  9 Mär  2017 virtuell1
drwx------  1 mr.robot  staff      16384 12 Okt  2011 virtuell10
drwx------  1 mr.robot  staff      16384 16 Jun  2014 virtuell2
drwx------  1 mr.robot  staff      16384 24 Feb  2014 virtuell3
drwx------  1 mr.robot  staff      16384 24 Jun  2016 virtuell4
drwx------  1 mr.robot  staff      16384 22 Jul  2016 virtuell5
drwx------  1 mr.robot  staff      16384 22 Jan 10:25 virtuell6
drwx------  1 mr.robot  staff      16384 11 Mai  2017 virtuell7
drwx------  1 mr.robot  staff      16384 16 Jan 12:24 virtuell8
drwx------  1 mr.robot  staff      16384 28 Mär  2014 virtuell9
```

This is not what we are expecting to see and we have absolutely zero clue as to why this might be happening...
We want the permissions for the client to be the exact same as on the server and we are all signed in as "corpuser" in Samba.

We did try to solve it using this [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1163422/samba-file-permissions-linux-server-mac-client/), but
sadly this didn't help us...

If you have any Idea then please feel free to comment or answer.

Comment: The permissions served by Samba and the on-disk permissions for a share might differ.  This is normal though.  And to change it you have to reconfigure Samba on how to serve the share data.

Comment: @ThomasWard 'corpuser' only exists on the Ubuntu Server, might that be the problem?

Comment: @ThomasWard how do we do that?

Comment: To answer both your questions: (1) From the little research I did: Samba isn't going to provide you the 'mount options' to set the user/group it's mounted as, though it might let you set the 'group' part.  I'm not a Samba expert, but I don't think that you can actually easily control how things are mounted at the client side from the server side, beyond the bitmasks.  (Mounting via  CIFS share, you can change the options via mount options locally on the client, but I don't think you can do this from the server).  (2) I'm not a Samba expert or I'd have posted this as an answer on how to do so.